# Google Anymote Discovery Identification String

Tags: google-tv, jmdns

According to the [Google Anymote Protocol documentation](https://developers.google.com/tv/remote/docs/index#discovery), a GoogleTV device can be discovered by sending mDNS packets.

A GoogleTV device should respond by identifying itself with the string "**_anymote._tcp.local**".

However, when I send out a mDNS packet, I receive a response with **NSZGT1-6017678.local**.

Unless the documentation is incorrect, I don't see a way to identify the device as a GTV device.

Is there something I am missing?

For example, only the airplay string actually returns any device in the following code:

```
String airplay = "_airplay._tcp.local.";
String gtv1 = "_anymote._tcp.local.";
String gtv2 = "_anymote._tcp.local";

JmDNS jmDNS = JmDNS.create();

jmDNS.addServiceListener(gtv1, new ServiceListener() {

    public void serviceResolved(ServiceEvent event) {}

    public void serviceRemoved(ServiceEvent event) {}

    public void serviceAdded(ServiceEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Service added: "  + event.getName() + " " +     event.getInfo().getName());             
    }
});
```

Comment: Try calling jmDNS.requestServiceInfo(gtv2, event.getName()); in serviceAdded(ServiceEvent event) method, which resulting serviceResolved(ServiceEvent event) method get called, see if you can get more info in serviceResolved(ServiceEvent event) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently mDNS is not used for discovering devices, although it can be, there's just no way to filter out just GTV devices that I have found.

Instead a message is broadcast on the network on port 9101.  See the following implementation:

http://code.google.com/p/google-tv-remote/source/browse/src/com/google/android/apps/tvremote/BroadcastDiscoveryClient.java